# Python process.teminate does not work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Why process is still alive after termination ? **TimeoutProcess** is my class derived from **Process** and doesn't overload the terminate method.

```
p = TimeoutProcess(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
p.start()
p.join(self.timeout_duration)
if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(p, p.is_alive())
    raise TimeoutError
if p.exception:
    raise p.exception
```

Here is the output

**(TimeoutProcess(TimeoutProcess-1, started), True)**

Comment: Just tried it using regular Process class and process was killed. Maybe a problem with your fn function?

Answer (score 0):

The `terminate` function issues an asynchronous termination request to the process via a signal (SIGTERM).

You still need to wait for its termination and collect the exit status using the `join` method.

```
p = TimeoutProcess(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
p.start()
p.join(self.timeout_duration)
if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()
    p.join(10)  # wait for process to correctly terminate
    if p.is_alive():  # in corner cases it might still happen
        raise TimeoutError
if p.exception:
    raise p.exception
```

If you still get TimeoutError, the child process might be swallowing the SIGTERM request.

Causes might be: the default behaviour for SIGTERM has been overwritten (signal handlers are inherited on Linux) or the function fn is stuck within a C loop (happens if you're using ctypes based APIs for example) and Python never gets control to actually release the resources.

A simple example of code dealing with such issues can be found [here](https://github.com/noxdafox/pebble/blob/futures/pebble/common.py#L25).